# How do I change the value of true or false to a text value type it I am checking the row in the entire table Note the table is of type datatables?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-templates

use django
How do I change the value of true or false to a text value type it I am checking the row in the entire table

| name item | type items | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 15.0 | True |
| item2 | 15.0 | False |

change values row active use jquery or django file view.py:

| name item | type items | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 15.0 | displayed |
| item2 | 15.0 | stope |

help please

Comment: So `True` always maps on `displayed`, and `False` on `stope`?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Can you share your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way is likely to specify choices for the `BooleanField`, so:

```
from django.db import models

ACTIVE_CHOICES = [
    (False, 'stope')
  , (True, 'displayed')
  ]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    active = models.BooleanField(choices=ACTIVE_CHOICES)
```

Then you can render the corresponding label in a template with:

```
{{ mymodelobject.get_active_display }}
```

It will also use these choices by default in a `ModelForm`, `ModelAdmin`, and serializers.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it is difficult to give a precise answer.

but the easiest way to set value based on a boolean in javascript is to use a ternary operator.

If true, active will be set to "displayed", if false, active will be set to "stope"

active = boolean_value ? "displayed" : "stope"